# Como exportar uma página HTML/C#(Razor) para PDF?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, razor, exportação

Possuo algumas tabelas simples e preciso exportá-las para PDF. Encontrei a biblioteca itextsharp, mas no arquivo comprimido existem muitas pastas e arquivos e não sei como adicionar a referência na minha aplicação.

Gostaria de ajuda para fazer a exportação, seja por essa biblioteca ou por outra, de preferência mostrando como adicionar a referência e algum exemplo de código.

Posteriormente se necessário adiciono o código que preciso exportar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o pacote NuGet RazorPDF2:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF2

Este pacote é meu. Qualquer coisa é só me mandar mensagem sobre bugs, me mencionando no chat ou no comentário de alguma das perguntas que respondi a respeito, ou fazer perguntas sobre a utilização.

## Exemplo usando Views em HTML

### Controller

```
    public ActionResult Exemplo(int id)
    {
        var model = context.Registros.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RegistroId == id);
        return new PdfActionResult(model);
    }
```

### View de Layout (View/Shared/_PdfLayout.cshtml)

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Meu Sistema</title>
    <style>
        html {
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        h1 {
            color: blue;
        }

        table {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-spacing: 0px;
        }

            table tr th {
                background-color: gray;
                color: white;
                padding: 2px;
            }

            table tr td {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 2px;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

### View

Faça uma View em HTML e Razor normal. Não esqueça de especificar o Layout da seguinte forma:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Título";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PdfLayout.cshtml";
}
```

## Exemplo usando tags do iTextSharp 4

### Controller

```
public RazorPDF.PdfResult PdfAction(int id)
{
    // Sua lógica para carregar as informações na variável "modelo"
    return new RazorPDF.PdfResult(modelo, "PdfAction");
}
```

### Views\SeuController\PdfAction.cshtml

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.SeuModelo

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PdfLayout.cshtml";
}

<paragraph style="font-family:Helvetica;font-size:18;font-style:italic;">
    <chunk style="font-weight:bold;">Seu Título</chunk>
</paragraph>

<paragraph style="font-family:Helvetica;">
    <chunk>Algumas palavras de cabeçalho</chunk>
</paragraph>

<table width="100%" cellpadding="0.5" cellspacing="0.5" widths="30;60" borderwidth="1.0" left="false" right="false" top="false" bottom="false" red="0" green="0" blue="0">
    <row>
        <cell>
            <chunk style="font-weight:bold;">Seu Label</chunk>
        </cell>
        <cell>
            <chunk style="">@Model.SuaInformacao</chunk>
        </cell>
    </row>
</table>
```

### _PdfLayout.cshtml

```
<itext creationdate="@DateTime.Now.ToString()" producer="RazorPDF">
    @RenderBody()
</itext>
```

Comment: Instalei já pelo Package Manager Console , qual referência devo adicionar na página para RazorPDF.PdfResult ser lido corretamente?

Comment: `using RazorPDF;` deve resolver tudo. No exemplo que eu coloquei, nem precisa desse `using`.

Comment: Esquece, eu tinha colocado no lugar errado. Já deu.

Comment: +1: Muito maneiro esse razor PDF.

Comment: Essa variavel "id" precisa mesmo? e a variavel "modelo", como que eu trabalho com ela? O que ela precisa ter?

Comment: Não, `id` é só um exemplo. `modelo` é uma variável que pode ser um *Model*, *ViewModel*, etc. Você vai usar como a variável `@model` da View, assim como numa *View Razor* normal.

Comment: Tem como gerar com o html da minha página, ou tenho que montar a estrutura do pdf por fora? E esse código ai usando table row e cell, que codigo é esse?

Comment: Tem um outro pacote NuGet chamado `Rotativa` que gera o PDF a partir do HTML gerado, mas este pacote eu não recomendo porque ele não funciona na Azure. Em todo caso, vou passar o link: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa

Comment: Mas respondendo, sim, você tem que montar a estrutura do PDF usando outro arquivo Razor. `row` e `cell` são tags do `iTextSharp`, que montam tabelas dentro do PDF.

Comment: Que linguagem de marcação é essa? Do proprio iTextSharp? Eu quero reproduzir meu documento usando ela. Onde encontro a documentação?

Comment: É a mesma documentação do iText. Não existe em português. O que existe é este tutorial: http://stderr.org/doc/libitext-java-doc/www/tutorial/ch07.html

Comment: A maioria da documentação está voltada ao uso do C#, mas segui a sua linha e montei via codigo. Porém não sei por exemplo como mudar a cor do fundo de uma celula. Você sabe?

Comment: Não sei se está certo, mas tente `<cell red="0" green="0" blue="255">`

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Lembra deste problema? Fiz um pacote novo que admite Views em HTML para a geração de PDFs, o RazorPDF2. Se quiser fazer alguns testes, veja a edição da resposta.

Comment: Aqui não funcionou, segui os passos acima: baixei o RazorPDF2 via Tools > NuGet Pachage Manager, instalei o iTextSharp 5.5.7, criei o Controller a View e a partial, daí ocorre um erro ao renderizar o html: **Detalhes da Exceção:** System.IO.IOException: The document has no pages.

Comment: @AdrianoCordeiro Este erro é do iTextSharp, não do RazorPDF2. Por favor, abra outra pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tentei usar o PdfSharp e o ItextSharp.

Para coisas simples você precisa escrever muito código sendo que deveria isto estar encapsulado facilitando a sua vida.

Eu sugiro usar a biblioteca IronPDF que tem uma boa documentação e muito mais fácil de usar.