# View Razor para PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, pdf

Estou precisando converter Views da minha aplicação MVC 5 em C# usando Razor para PDF.
Já procurei, e as ferramentas free dependem do iTextSharp, que pelo eu pesquisei tem uma marcação diferente.

Porém preciso converter uma página HTML qualquer para PDF, ou seja, converter minhas páginas existente com o menor custo de tempo e manutenção futura.

Alguma sugestão, free ou paga que vocês utilizam.
Existe alguma solução que coloca cabeçalho e rodapé de um HTML qualquer?

Answer (score 2):

Duas opções:

- RazorPDF2 (pacote de minha autoria, tem suporte a todos os documentos do antigo pacote RazorPDF + iTextSharp 5): https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF2/

  - Recebe como entrada uma View em HTML usando o método `PdfActionResult`;
  - Pode receber como entrada uma View com tags do iTextSharp 4, usando o método `PdfResult`;
  - Exemplos usando Tags do iTextSharp 4: https://github.com/RazorAnt/RazorPDFSample
  - [Resposta em que coloco um exemplo completo com tags do iTextSharp 4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10716/como-exportar-uma-p%C3%A1gina-html-crazor-para-pdf/10717#10717)
- Rotativa (não funciona no Azure): https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa

  - Recebe como entrada uma `View` em HTML;
  - Exemplos: https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/tree/master/Rotativa.Demo

Comment: Com o RazorPDF consigo pegar uma view qualquer e transformar em PDF, ou tem que usar as Tags do iTextSharp?

Comment: @marlon.tiedt Você tem que montar um Razor usando as tags do iTextSharp. Caso você queira transformar uma `View` em PDF, melhor usar o Rotativa.

Answer (score 0):

Qual o problema com a notação do iTextSharp?
Seguindo a notação como [está aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19398426/3939522) funcionou comigo, seguindo o processo:

1 - salvando o conteúdo da página que quero converter para pdf
2 - escapando as tags (para poder enviar para a controler) e enviando para a controler
3 - [da controller] enviando para o métdo que converte (que é o mesmo da resposta) 
4 - reconvertendo a string (aplicando as tags novamente)
5 efetivamente seguindo o que estava no post (a diferença é que o 'html' é a minha string contendo tudo o que eu quero salvar em pdf)

Comment: o problema do itextsharp é que é pago e o valor abusivo =)